# My stylesheet did not load, but the paths is correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I copy a html to my project, and copy the stylesheets too, but the html did not load the stylesheet.

[image]

With the error:

> ReferenceError: Layout is not defined

You can see it in the picture:

[image]

My project directory is below:

[image]

The stylesheet link path is correct, but why my html did not load the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `asset_path` helper or a helper that uses that helper, such as `stylesheet_link_tag`.

Comment: Since you didn't put your css under `app/assets/stylesheets`, you probably need to give a relative path to the file when you use the helpers, such as: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'global/css/components.css' %>`

Comment: the `Layout is not defined` is related to the asset_path helper?

Comment: I am not sure about that error, especially given the foreign language.